# multiple highcharts on one page

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, highcharts, each

I'm wishing to render multiple charts using mysql data, there will be more or less charts depending on a particular search.  I've successfully created a single chart, and my php file echoes the required json format nicely.

Now, what I would like is to be able to loop over an array and draw new charts based on the array vales being parsed to the php which in turn provides different json data to be rendered.

by the way, my javasript is very limited so here goes my code and thoughts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var chart;
        var venue = <?php echo json_encode($venue_name); ?>; /* parsed to php file */
        var distances = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>; /* array to be looped over */
        $(document).ready(function() {

            var options = {
                    ....
                series: []
                    ....
             };

             //
            $.each(distances, function() {
               $.each(this, function(name, value) {
               // do some ajax magic here:... 
                GET 'myphpfile.php?venue='+venue+'&'+distances

                  function drawNewChart(){
                      $('#mainSite').append('<div id="container" style="float:left; display:inline"></div>');

                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options); 
        });
    });        

    </script>
```

What I have learnt is that I cannot loop an include php file which has the completed php and jquery...

Answer (score 0):

this will create other charts. every time u want create new chart , u must give new name chart like i do `chart2`

paste this bellow and it will give you other chart.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var chart2;
    var venue2 = <?php echo json_encode($venue_name); ?>; /* <---use other variable here of $venue_name */
    var distances2 = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>; /* <---use other variable of $data */
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var options = {
                ....
            series: []
                ....
         };

         //
        $.each(distances2, function() {
           $.each(this, function(name, value) {
           // do some ajax magic here:... 
            GET 'myphpfile.php?venue2='+venue2+'&'+distances2

              function drawNewChart(){
                  $('#mainSite').append('<div id="container" style="float:left; display:inline"></div>');

            chart2 = new Highcharts.Chart(options); 
    });
});        

</script>
```

Comment: thanks good mood... I guess what I'm really after is how to dynamically draw many charts from mysql/php queries.  I'll keep searching...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using many variables, you can push your charts to array.

```
var charts = [];
charts.push(new Highcharts(options));
```

Then you can avoid of using index etc.